# Multithreading atomics a b printing 00 for memory_order_relaxed

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, stdatomic

In the below code the write to a in foo is stored in store buffer and  not visible to the ra in bar. Similarly the write to b in bar is not visible to rb in foo and they print 00.

```
// g++ -O2 -pthread axbx.cpp ; while [ true ]; do ./a.out | grep "00"; done prints 00 within 1min
#include<atomic>
#include<thread>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
atomic<long> a,b;
long ra,rb;
void foo(){
        a.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);
        rb=b.load(memory_order_relaxed);
}
void bar(){
        b.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);
        ra=a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
}
int main(){
  thread t[2]{ thread(foo),thread(bar)};
  t[0].join();t[1].join();
  if((ra==0) && (rb==0)) printf("00\n"); // each cpu store buffer writes not visible to other threads.
}
```

The below code is almost the same as above except the variable b is removed and both foo and bar have the same variable 'a' and the return value is stored in ra1 and ra2. In this case i never get a "00" atleast after running for 5 minutes.

1. In the second case why doesn't it print 00 ? How come writes to x
   are not stored in cpu cache for both threads and then print 00 ?
2. Does it have anything to do with x86_64 but it prints 00 on arm/arm64/power ?
3. If arm/arm64/power prints 00 , will a smp_mb() after store in foo and bar fix it ?

```
// g++ -O2 -pthread axbx.cpp ; while [ true ]; do ./a.out | grep "00"; done doesn't print 00 within 5 min
#include<atomic>
#include<thread>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
atomic<long> a,b;
long ra1,ra2;
void foo(){
        a.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);
        ra1=a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
}
void bar(){
        a.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);
        ra2=a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
}
int main(){
  thread t[2]{ thread(foo),thread(bar)};
  t[0].join();t[1].join();
  if((ra1==0) && (ra2==0)) printf("00\n"); // each cpu store buffer writes not visible to other threads.
}
```

Comment: Generally don't mix Linux `smp_mb()` with `std::atomic`, just use `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` or whatever memory-order you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.store(1, mo_relaxed)` is *sequenced before* `a.load` in the same thread (in both foo and bar), so both loads must see that store result (or another later store value).  **That makes it impossible for either load to see the initial 0.**

**A thread *always* sees *its own* operations in program order, even if they're on atomic objects using `mo_relaxed`.**  That's basically equivalent to making sure the stores and loads happen in asm (in program order), but without any extra barriers to prevent runtime reordering when observed by other threads, [like if you'd used `volatile`.  (But don't)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118).  The cardinal rule of out-of-order execution is "don't break single-threaded code".

---

And BTW, you're actually correct that the value can be [forwarded](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/) directly from the [store buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) before it hits L1d cache and becomes globally visible.  (Because you didn't use `mo_seq_cst`; seq_cst loads can't happen until previous seq_cst stores are globally visible.  e.g. on x86 it would have to compile to an `xchg` store, or `mov` + `mfence`.  Semi-related: [Globally Invisible load instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609934/globally-invisible-load-instructions) about where load results come from on x86, although the general point about store-forwarding applies to most mainstream CPUs including most ARM.)

So in practice the loads are very likely to see the `1` stored by their own thread, not the `1` from the other thread, because it will compile to asm that allows the store to forward to the load, and the load is right after so it's probably already in the process of executing and waiting for the store-data to be forwarded before there's any window for the other thread's store to be visible between them, unless an interrupt arrives between the store and load.

You could check by storing a `1` and a `2`, for example, to see if you always get `12` or sometimes get `21`.

---

Your analysis of why you can see `00` in your version using 2 variables is pretty sloppy.

> In the below code the write to a in foo is stored in store buffer and not visible to the ra in bar. Similarly the write to b in bar is not visible to rb in foo

Yes the store buffer is the normal cause of StoreLoad reordering, and **if** both `foo` and `bar` happen to execute at nearly the same time, then yes both loads can happen and grab the old values before either store can get itself committed to L1d cache.  So if that does happen, then yes it's because of the store buffer.

But the store buffer is always trying to drain itself as fast as possible and commit pending stores to L1d where they're globally visible.  That's why it's rare to actually see `00`.  Usually one core will get exclusive ownership of the cache line and commit its store before the other core's load can run.

It's definitely not true that a write to `a` *will* be invisible to a load in another thread.  It might or might not happen.

(Semi related: [Store Load](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) reordering is the "most important" one for performance, and the most expensive one to block.  For example x86 asm *always* blocks the other kinds, being program-order + store-forwarding, so stuff reordering 2 stores wrt. each other can only happen at compile-time on x86.  [How does memory reordering help processors and compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725497/how-does-memory-reordering-help-processors-and-compilers))

Comment: I have an x86_64 machine but can we verify these for different architecture in some way. I tried qemu-static-aarch64, qemu-ppc64-static but qemu docs says it will execute in the underlying cpu order which is underlying x86_64 .So  i can hardly verify these. Also gcc/clang tsan doesn't check  memory_order. Should this be another question ?

Comment: @nvn: No, all CPUs will always give you `11` for your 2nd version, because that's what ISO C++ requires.

Comment: i'll ask another question on that.

Comment: @nvn: On what?  I don't see what question is still unresolved.  As I said in my answer (after the last edit), the cardinal rule of out-of-order exec is to not break single-threaded execution.  And even the first version mentioned store-forwarding: that's how a CPU manages to see its own stores before their globally visible, instead of having every reload of a recent store have to stall until the store buffer committed it to L1d cache.

Answer (score 2):

> In the below code the write to a in foo is stored in store buffer and not visible to the ra in bar. Similarly the write to b in bar is not visible to rb in foo

Neither of these is true. Whether `bar` sees the value written to `a` by `foo` is indeterminate, but not undefined. All atomic operations on the same memory execute in some global order determined by the implementation. `bar` could see `a` as 0 or 1; either is perfectly legitimate, and relaxed memory order changes nothing about this.

> In the second case why doesn't it print 00 ? How come writes to x are not stored in cpu cache for both threads and then print 00 ?

As previously stated, all atomic operations on the same memory execute in some global order. Also, all operations on the same memory in the same thread execute in the program order (ie: no reordering). So within the same thread, your `a.load` will retrieve either the value that was just set to `a` or the value some other thread set to `a`. It will *never* just skip the initial store in that thread.