# Why is StoreLoad more expensive than other barrier types?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

There is already an [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475025/why-is-a-store-load-barrier-considered-expensive#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20that%20a%20store,STORE%20operations%20across%20the%20barrier.&text=This%20would%20prevent%20the%20LD,the%20previous%20store%20instructions%20complete.) about why StoreLoad barrier is expensive, and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27477887/4794308) explained it is expensive because the StoreLoad barrier blocked the Load until the (potentially expensive) Store operation has finished.

However, that does not fully make sense to me because the other barrier types (e.g. LoadStore, LoadLoad, StoreStore) seem to have the same property as the operation after the barrier will always be blocked until the one before finishes. I am wondering if/why StoreLoad is always considered intrinsically different from other barriers in perf respective?

I do understand that on particular platforms with strong memory models(e.g. X86), the other three barrier types are free from CPU point of view so only compiler barrier is needed. But what about other platforms without strong memory model guarantee (e.g. ARM, PowerPC)? Is StoreLoad still more expensive?

Comment: Stores have to be buffered in the store buffer ([can a speculatively executed cpu branch contain opcodes that access RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64141366)).  Only StoreLoad has to drain it, other barriers just have to wait for *loads*, or order stores wrt. each other.

Comment: Also related: [How does memory reordering help processors and compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37725497) re: why StoreLoad reordering is something CPUs really want to do all the time.

Answer (score 1):

With intel x86-64, this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475025/why-is-a-store-load-barrier-considered-expensive#comment71586035_27477887) has said 'LoadLoad, StoreStore and LoadStore' are ensured by hardware (i.e. [acquire and release semantics](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/#IDComment721195741)), so they are not expensive.

The basic operations of StoreStore is not changed after reordering although intel won't reorder them which is shown in Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual (Order Number: 325462-079US) vol.3-A "9.2.3.2 Neither Loads Nor Stores Are Reordered with Like Operations". So the overhead is not high although having the store buffer. (i.e. 'order stores wrt. each other' in the comment above)

As to other architecture, hope someone can fill the empty slot here. I am not an expert.

**Edited**:

For Arm, StoreLoad also implies [buffer drain](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101051/0002/Memory-system/Store-buffer/Store-buffer-draining) at least for Cortex-M55.